# How to install pytest using chef

Tags: python, chef-infra, pytest, chef-solo, cookbook

I have downloaded the python cookbook from opscode using the *knife cookbook download site* command. I ran it with chef-solo on ubuntu and it works perfectly fine. I also need pytest installed. I don't seem to find a cookbook for pytest on opscode. How should i go about it? I am new to chef, so don't have much idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new recipe to install pytest
using this LWRPs included in the python cookbook

```
python_pip "PYtest" do
   version "2.5.2"
end
```

Steps

1 - create a new cookbook (knife cookbook create NAME_COOKBOOK)

2 - Add dependency metadata.rb (vi metadata.rb)

> depends 'python'

3 - Include default recipe (vi recipe/default.rb)

```
include_recipe 'python::default'
```

4 - install with pip supplier, PYtest (vi recipe/default.rb)

```
python_pip "pytest" do
   version "2.5.2"
end
```

5 - Add to run_list

```
   "run_list": [
     "recipe [NAME_COOKBOOK]"]
```

It is a minimal version and is to begin to try chef.

maybe this link can help

http://gettingstartedwithchef.com/

sorry for my English

Best Regards